# Bash code interfering with monitoring software

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, terminal

I have a login script that runs when users logs into a Linux machine.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$SSH_TTY" ]; then
```

This script is interfering with a monitoring software that also connects over SSH. The script requests "press any key to continue" with a read -p -n1 -s portion. How can I omit this script only when the monitoring service is "logging in?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I omit this script only when the monitoring service is
>   "logging in?"

Assuming this login script is in `/etc/profile.d` you could do this:

```
if [[ $(whoami) != "monitor_user" ]]; then
   <run rest of script>
fi
```

You will of course need to change `"monitor_user"` into the *proper* username for the monitoring user/agent.